# How do I use Extended ASCII characters in a PHP/PDF document generated by FPDF?

Tags: php, character-encoding, fpdf, extended-ascii

I am trying to create a document that contains Extended ASCII characters. For text coming from the client the following works:

```
// Convert from UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1 - Deal with Spanish characters
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF-8');
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){
    $post[$key] = iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1", $value);
}

$pdf->Cell(0, 0, $post["Name"], 0, 1);
```

However, I can't get text in the PHP file to work. For example:

```
$name = "José";
```

I don't know what encoding the variable uses. As a result, I can't convert it to ISO-8859-1. The é gets mangled.

**Edit:**
I am rewriting a program that generates PDF documents (some in Spanish). If I copy text from the existing PDFs, I get the following: (which looks normal in the PDF document and in the IDE but can't be printed with FPDF using either CP1252 or ISO-8859-1 fonts).

```
$Name = "José" // Jos\x65\xcc\x81 - I have no idea what encoding is used for the é
```

Changing the extended characters to UTF-8 solves the problem:

```
$Name = "José" // Jos\xC3\xA9  - UTF-8
```

1. Does anyone know what kind of encoding I am copying from the existing PDFs?
2. Is there a way to convert it to UTF-8?
3. Can users enter this stuff into a browser?

When I convert the UTF-8 encoded characters to ISO-8859-1 for output to FPDF, the PDF contains the three character encoded version of the é.

**2nd Edit:** [Unicode equivalence from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence)

> Unicode provides two notions, canonical equivalence and
>   compatibility. Code point sequences that are defined as canonically
>   equivalent are assumed to have the same appearance and meaning when
>   printed or displayed. For example, the code point U+006E (the Latin
>   lowercase "n") followed by U+0303 (the combining tilde "◌̃") is
>   defined by Unicode to be canonically equivalent to the single code
>   point U+00F1 (the lowercase letter "ñ" of the Spanish alphabet).
>   Therefore, those sequences should be displayed in the same manner,
>   should be treated in the same way by applications such as
>   alphabetizing names or searching, and may be substituted for each
>   other.

Which is the long way of paraphrasing @smith's comment that I just need to get TCPDF or something that will properly handle UTF-8. It should be noted that I am getting the error in PHP's iconv, so I not entirely sure that it can be made to go away by switching to TCPDF.

Comment: one of the reasons i use TCPDF is  its superior utf-8 support.

Comment: @smith can you point me to an example of some code that sends local variables with Extended ASCII characters to the functions that generate the pdf document?

Comment: im suggesting you change to a better pdf generation library TCPDF. https://tcpdf.org/

Comment: @smith thanks for the pointer. i was of the opinion that the problem was with PHP and not with FPDF. That turned out to be correct. TCPDF seems to be a much better package with much better examples. I copied the text from their example and it worked! Apparently the é I was using was not UTF-8.

Comment: @smith can you check to see if the three byte encoding works with TCPDF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that to use extended ASCII characters one needs to pick and encoding and use it throughout. In my case, I went with UTF-8 encoded characters and used them everywhere. My original problem stemmed from my mistake in copying text from a PDF document which was encoded in the canonically equivalent format. Once I used UTF-8 encoded characters everywhere my problems went away.